# How would I get this code to update every minute?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to make a countdown timer and I want the time left to be displayed. However, when the code runs and I set to a number, for example 5 the time left is just 5 it doesn't keep updating. How would I get it to update?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Timer</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="popup-content">
    <h6 id=title></h6>
    <p>Enter the time(in minutes) you want to spend on this page: </p>
    <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="60" id="textBox">
    <button onclick="ductivity()" id="set">Set Timer</button> Time Left:
    <p id="timeLeft"></p>
  </div>
  <script>
    function ductivity() {
      var x = document.getElementById("textBox").value;
      var start = Date.now();
      var elapsed = (Date.now() - start) / 1000; //time elapsed in seconds
      var y = x - elapsed;
      if (y >= 0) {
        document.getElementById("timeLeft").innerHTML = y;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("timeLeft").innerHTML = "TIMES UP";
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: Code with [one-letter variables](https://www.codereadability.com/i-n-k-single-letter-variable-names/) loses my interest fairly rapidly.

Comment: Oops sorry about my one letter variables. I should really stop doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need something that will continue on instead of a one and done function so using setInterval(function(),1000); below works as shown in https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Timer</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="popup-content">
<h6 id=title></h6>
<p>Enter the time(in minutes) you want to spend on this page: </p>
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="60" id="textBox">
<button onclick="ductivity()" id="set">Set Timer</button>
Time Left: <p id="timeLeft"></p>
</div>
<script>
function ductivity(){
 let start=Date.now();  
 let interval = setInterval(function() {
  let x = document.getElementById("textBox").value;
  let elapsed = (Date.now() - start)/1000;//time elapsed in seconds
  let y = Math.floor((x * 60) - elapsed);
  if(y>=0){
    document.getElementById("timeLeft").innerHTML = "Seconds Left:" + y;
  }
  else{
      document.getElementById("timeLeft").innerHTML = "TIMES UP";
  }
 },1000);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval()`. See details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).